# Matlab: Save image frames as YCbCr video

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb, ycbcr

So I have **10 separate image frames** of YCbCr format. How can I export it as a YCbCr video in Matlab so that it can be viewed through a supported video player?

**Update-1**

```
for Frame_Index = 1: frames
    YCbCr_Movie_Structure_Array(Frame_Index).cdata = uint8(images(Frame_Index));
end
```

I'm getting the error:
Conversion to uint8 from cell is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Expoting Frames to a Video File

Not sure if you want to keep the frames in the YCbCr colour-space but if that's the case... One method is to save all the individual frames into a structure that has the fields/members `'cdata'` and `'colormap'`. After looping through the frames and saving them to the structure the structure can be exported to a video file. To export the video to file a video object must first be created using the `VideoWriter()` function. The entire structure can then be written to the video object and transitively the file by using the `WriteVideo()` function. It is good to keep in mind to `open()` and `close()` the video object before performing any reading and writing from this object similar to how text files are handled. In the example below the video is exported to a `.mp4` file. The frame rate and quality can be configured by the dot properties `.FrameRate` and `.Quality` respectively.

### Method 1: Using a Structure → Video Object (File)

```
%Creating 10 test images/frames%
Frame_1 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_2 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_3 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_4 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_5 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_6 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_7 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_8 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_9 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_10 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);

Number_Of_Frames = 10;
[Video_Height,Video_Width,Number_Of_Channels] = size(Frame_1);

%Creating a matrix with dimensions of the video with three channels%
Colour_Channel_Matrix = zeros(Video_Height,Video_Width,3,'uint8');

%Creating a video structure to hold all the frames%
YCbCr_Movie_Structure_Array = struct('cdata',Colour_Channel_Matrix, 'colormap', []);

%Scanning the frames into the video structure%
for Frame_Index = 1: Number_Of_Frames
    YCbCr_Movie_Structure_Array(Frame_Index).cdata = uint8(eval("Frame_" + num2str(Frame_Index)));
end

%Creating a video object to save the video structure to%
Video_Object = VideoWriter('Saved_Video.mp4','MPEG-4'); 
Video_Object.FrameRate = 30; 
Video_Object.Quality = 100;
open(Video_Object);

writeVideo(Video_Object,YCbCr_Movie_Structure_Array);
close(Video_Object);
```

---

### Method 2: Directly Into Video Object (File)

This method is a lot quicker but losses some flexibility in manipulating and checking/validating frame before writing them to a file.

```
%Creating 10 test images%
Frame_1 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_2 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_3 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_4 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_5 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_6 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_7 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_8 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_9 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);
Frame_10 = randi(255,[400 400 3]);

Images = {Frame_1,Frame_2,Frame_3,Frame_4,Frame_5,Frame_6,Frame_7,Frame_8,Frame_9,Frame_10};
Number_Of_Frames = length(Images);

%Creating a video object to save the video structure to%
Video_Object = VideoWriter('Saved_Video.mp4','MPEG-4'); 
Video_Object.FrameRate = 30; 
Video_Object.Quality = 100;
open(Video_Object);

%Scanning the frames into the video structure%
for Frame_Index = 1: Number_Of_Frames    
    writeVideo(Video_Object,uint8(cell2mat(Images(Frame_Index))));
end

close(Video_Object);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation. I have all the frames in images array. Each frame is 352x240x3 uint8. How can I use this images array instead? I added the error I'm getting while trying to use this. Thanks.

Comment: Try this `YCbCr_Movie_Structure_Array(Frame_Index).cdata = uint8(cell2mat(images(Frame_Index)));`

Comment: That did the trick. I'm wondering though, is there any way to do it without using a struct though?

Comment: Yes, there is, each frame can be written one by one into the video object, but that method also involves a loop. This method has the benefit that  `implay()` can be used on the structure to view the video and also the values of each frame can be viewed in the structure.

Comment: Added the second way to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: If I want to save the frames I had with .yuv extension, what changes should I make?

Comment: Not too sure about the details about that, but here’s a question going over it: [YUV File Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194285/yuv-file-format)